# Search Skype for Users by Country

Tags: api, skype

In the Skype client, I can search for users by country. Is there any way to do this via the API?

Something like:

```
SEARCH USERS name COUNTRY = Estonia
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible via the API. The only way I have found you can do this is by using xautomation (linux), which allows you to program mouse and keyboard movements. There is a similar program, SendKeys, for Windows.